# c# MVC Entity framework model property of type list containing multiple types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a C# MVC project combined with Entity Framework, where I have a view page (Create page) on which the users will need to fill in the required data. I got a model something like the code below. Where the user has a `Boat` and can select its properties.

```
public class Boat {
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Slowboat : Boat {
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public virtual Engine SpeedSource { get; set; }
}

public class Speedboat : Boat {
    public virtual List<?> SpeedSource { get; set; }
    public int Topspeed {get; set; }
}

public class Engine {
    public string EningeType { get; set; }
    public int Horsepower { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Sail {
    public int SailCount { get; set; }
    public List<int> SailSizes { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Everything goes well, a Speedboat has a couple of sails **or** an engine.
The problem arises when a Speedboat has one or more Engine(s) **and** Sail.

I tried using `List<object>` type, but this didn't store my data into my database on posting. A kind of wrapper class like underneath is quick solution but there needs to be a better one in my opinion.

```
public class SpeedPower {
    public Engine Engine_ { get; set; }
    public Sail Sail_ { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is: how do you store multiple types into one list?

Thanks for a possible solution.

Edit: so as Thomas Flinkow suggested I can make an interface with some of the mutual properties.

```
public interface ISpeedSource {
    string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Speedboat : Boat {
    public virtual List<ISpeedSource> SpeedSource { get; set; }
    public int Topspeed {get; set; }
}
```

So will the other proprties be saved if I use the interface like this?

Comment: It sounds like the conceptual modeling is broken.  An `Engine` and a `Sail` are *not* the same thing.  So what exactly *is* a "SpeedSource"?  Maybe your boats could have a collection of Engines and a collection of Sails as *separate* collections?  Some boats simply have empty collections of one or the other.  Unless you can define a common interface of what a "SpeedSource" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all your *"speed sources"* like this:

```
public class Engine : ISpeedSource { ... }

public class Sail : ISpeedSource { ... }
```

with `ISpeedSource` being a simple (maybe empty, but not necessarily) interface

```
public interface ISpeedSource { ... }
```

And then have your `Speedboat` class like this:

```
public class Speedboat : Boat 
{
    public virtual List<ISpeedSource> SpeedSource { get; set; }
    public int Topspeed { get; set; }
}
```

---

<sub>You might want to overthink your design as David suggested, because [empty interfaces should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1040-avoid-empty-interfaces).</sub>

Comment: As you state, empty interfaces should be avoided.  More specifically in this case, when posting a form from the client, I doubt the model binder would know what to do with an empty interface.  If all the model binder knows is that it's a collection of `ISpeedSource` and an `ISpeedSource` has no properties, it probably wouldn't store anything useful in that collection.

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow I like the suggestion of the interface because there a a few common properties, so I edited my question. But I also have a common class that has a `List` that will be of a different size by the type of "speedSource", would it be enough to limit this `List` size on the front-end of my application?

Comment: @Kitesaint1309 If I understand this correctly, you want the interface to have a `List<SpeedSize>`? If so, you could just do this: `interface { IList<SpeedSource> MyList { get; }` if it isn't absolutely necessary to restrict the size.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow yes something like that, I my case it would be something like `interface { IList<string> CrewNames { get; set; }` which is dependent on the type of boat (sailboats need more crew then engine boats).

Comment: @Kitesaint1309 alright, that would be perfectly fine and imo should work.

Comment: I am going to try to get this working, the only that could arise is that I sometimes have an empty `List<ISpeedSource>` inside my view when the user is entering the details of his/her boat. How could I avoid this?

Comment: @Kitesaint1309 well, that depends on what you want to do: do you want to enforce every boat to always have at least one `ISpeedSource`?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Probably yes, but there won't be a SpeedSource every boat has. So making a default SpeedSource isn't possible.

Comment: @Kitesaint1309 I might be missing something here, but why is it a problem then? Can you not have an empty / `null` `List`?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow having an empty list when creating the view is no problem at all, but when I `post` it to my controller it complains that I am trying to make an instance of an interface. I just add instances of the classes that inherit from `ISpeedSource` to my view, what would work.